# Python asyncio: handling exceptions in gather() - documentation unclear?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The [documentation for asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) says that

> If return_exceptions is `False` (default), the first raised exception is
>   immediately propagated to the task that awaits on `gather()`. Other
>   awaitables in the aws sequence **won’t be cancelled** and will continue to
>   run.

However, from a simple test it seems that if one of the tasks raises an exception when return_exceptions is `False`, all other awaitable are cancelled (or to be more precise, in case the terminology is not clear to me, the other awaitables do not finish their job):

```
import asyncio

async def factorial(name, number, raise_exception=False):
    # If raise_exception is True, will raise an exception when
    # the loop counter > 3
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        print(f'  Task {name}: Compute factorial({i})...')

        if raise_exception and i > 3:
            print(f'  Task {name}: raising Exception')
            raise Exception(f'Bad Task {name}')

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        f *= i
    print(f'==>> Task {name} DONE: factorial({number}) = {f}')
    return f

async def main():
    tasks = [factorial('A', 5),  # this will not be finished
             factorial('B', 10, raise_exception=True),
             factorial('C', 2)]

    try:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print('Results:', results)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Got an exception:', e)

asyncio.run(main())
```

What this piece of code is doing, just to make it simpler, it defines 3 tasks and call `asyncio.gather()` on them. One of the tasks raises an exception before one of the others is done, and this other task is not finished.

Actually, I cannot even make sense with what the documentations says - if an exception is raised and caught by the task awaiting on `gather`, I would not even be able to get the returned results (even if the other task would, somehow, get done).

Am I missing anything, or is there a problem with the documentation?

This was tested with Python 3.7.2.

Comment: What you may be missing here is that the other tasks have not been canceled, you're just not seeing their result, since the asyncio loop has stopped running, since you've only executed the loop as far as the exception so far and are then not continuing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Scatter-Gather pattern in parallelism

The `gather` function is primarily designed for the [Scatter-Gather pattern](https://www.gaurgaurav.com/patterns/scatter-gather/). In this pattern, when you need to calculate something from  **all** task-results (e.g. in an aggregation function), the *gather* function is handy. The switch `return_exceptions` controls whether a single failure should invalidate the aggregated result.
By default, any failure will be [immediately propagated to](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)  the  *gather* task.
This behavior is desired in aggregation tasks like `sum(await gather(*tasks))` because the *sum* becomes invalid due to a single failure.
However, **no task will be cancelled or altered in any way** by   `gather`.
It is merely one observable, waiting and gathering information quietly.

Your question 1:

> I cannot even make sense with what the documentations says - if an exception is raised ..., I would not even be able to get the returned results

Usually you can and need to define multiple observables
in a Scatter-Gather job.
After one *gather* fails, the main routine should continue with another `gather` or [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) or `as_completed` or `asyncio.sleep`.
Remember that tasks are still running and the *Future* objects are still there. By design, Scatter-Gather tasks should be independent, and the *gather* operation  **should not have any side effects**, so that you can continue to handle those awaitables *independently*, e.g., by querying their `tasks[i].result()` or explicitly killing them.

Question 2:

> Am I missing anything, or is there a problem with the documentation?

In your test program, no other tasks (observables) are defined after catching the exception, so the main program simply exits, which gives you an illusion that all tasks are cancelled.
They are indeed cancelled when the event loop are closed by `asyncio.run(main())`, some milliseconds after catching the exception.
By adding another waiting task, either `await asyncio.wait(tasks)` or simply `await asyncio.sleep(20)` at the end of `main()`, those worker tasks will have their chance to complete. Thus the documentation is correct.

Your test program can be considered as a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of calculation tasks. The *gather* task is your *root* target passed to `asyncio.run`. Therefore, when the only mission fails, all sub-tasks are aborted.

-- *updated in 2023*

---

*original answer*

I've run your code and got the following output, as expected from documentation.

```
  Task C: Compute factorial(2)...
  Task A: Compute factorial(2)...
  Task B: Compute factorial(2)...
==>> Task C DONE: factorial(2) = 2
  Task A: Compute factorial(3)...
  Task B: Compute factorial(3)...
  Task A: Compute factorial(4)...
  Task B: Compute factorial(4)...
  Task B: raising Exception
Got an exception: Bad Task B
  Task A: Compute factorial(5)...
==>> Task A DONE: factorial(5) = 120
```

## What's going on

1. Tasks A,B and C are submitted to the queue;
2. All tasks are running while C finishes earliest.
3. Task B raises and exception.
4. The `await asyncio.gater()` returns immediately and `print('Got an exception:', e)` to the screen.
5. Task A continues to run and print "==>> Task A DONE ..."

## What's wrong with your test

As @deceze commented,
your program exited immediately after the exception was caught and `main()` returns. Thus, the tasks A and C are terminated because the entire process dies, not because of cancellation.

To fix it, add `await asyncio.sleep(20)` to the end of the `main()` function.

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean, but it raises a few questions: so if I use `raise_exception=True`, then there is no point in getting the returned value of `gather`? Since then I cannot guarantee that I'll get it. In other words, either I use `raise_exception=False` (the default) and then I can wait for the returned value of `gather` and process it, or I use `raise_exception=True` without trying to use the returned value. Also, in the latest case, How should I wait, in case one of the tasks had raised an exception, for the other tasks? Shall I use callbacks in that case?

Comment: Do you mean `return_exceptions`?

Comment: If you set `return_exceptions=True` the exception object will be returned and put in the `results` of `gather()`. For your example, it will print out `Results: [120, Exception('Bad Task B',), 2]`. In short, you can trust the returned value of `gather()`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `return_exceptions`, of course. I know that when it is `True` I can trust the returned value of `gather()`. The other case, when it is `False`, is less clear to me - how should I handle the other tasks, those that were not done when an exceptions was raised, but I guess I'll be able to figure that out now.

Comment: @amitr: I have the same question, did you find out a solution?

Comment: @In78 - sorry, it's been a long time and I haven't been using Python or this code for quiet time, and, unfortunately, I'm not sure what was the solution.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Adding wait time to let task A complete after the exception happened works technically, but this is just a workaround, not a solution. The answer from Raydel is a real solution.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Nope. The question asks specifically the behavior of `asyncio.gather`. While `as_complete` may be a good solution in many scenario, it doesn't answer this question. In this toy program, `as_complete` fails to preserve the order of the tasks.

Comment: Ok, my main point here is though that I think it is a bad idea to suggest adding artificial wait time as a fix. I am sure you did not mean it that way, but people might just  copy/paste this into their code.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Fair point. I have rewritten the answer to address more general questions than the original one. It is usually a bad practice to add hard coded wait/sleep time, but it is also bad to wait for workers without a timeout, especially for predictable CPU-intensive concurrent workload like this. Thus, I still keep the `sleep` option here, together with `wait`, `as_complete`, .... The sleep is a dirty way to wait with a timeout.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the main question here is to use [asyncio.as_complete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html). Change your `main()` function code to:

```
async def main():
    tasks = [factorial('A', 5),  # this will not be finished
             factorial('B', 10, raise_exception=True),
             factorial('C', 2)]


    # Handle results in the order the task are completed
    # if exeption you can handle that as well. 
    for coroutine in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        try:
            results = await coroutine
        except Exception as e:
            print('Got an exception:', e)
        else:
            print('Results:', results)
```